# Entity Framework change table name dynamically

Tags: entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

We have a web application in Spanish, and we want to localize it to another language. I would like to query the original table i.e. countries if the visitor is a spanish spoken or countries_en if the visitor is a english spoken. 
Is this possible in EF (we use EF 6) and LINQ? How? Because the LINQ query would switch tables dynamically checking UICulture.

Comment: I would suggest changing your design. Add a language field to your countries table and then simply use a `where` clause to get the english vs. spanish (vs other languages in the future) values.

Comment: @CraigW. is right. SQL already has a feature for getting a subset of the data. It's called a where clause. Switching between parallel tables is a very poor substitute for adding another column to a single table, but it's a surprisingly common antipattern. Everything in SQL, and everything in EF and ADO.NET and everything else in the world, is designed to work well with where clauses. Nothing, anywhere, is designed to work well with your design. That means it'll be making your life difficult in a lot of ways for a long time.